# rust relative array indexing

Tags: rust, unsigned-integer, integer-arithmetic

I'm a fairly advanced programmer (experience in Java, Python, C#, C, C++) who is now trying to learn Rust for the first time.
Rust is quite different from any language I've tried before, so I'm struggling quite a bit.
To get to know the language I'm implementing a little game.

At some point in my code, I would like to access an element from my 'board' and a surrounding element.
If my element is at the edge of the board (index 0 or index max), I want a clipped value (eg index 0 - 1 == 0)
If I simplify this use case, I'm trying to access an index from an array and a relative index.
Below is a very minimal example:

```rust
fn get_elements(array: &Vec<char>, i: usize, dx: i8) -> (char, char) {
    let center = array[i];
    let other = array[i+dx];
    (center, other)
}

fn main() {
    let data = vec!['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
    let (c, o) = get_elements(&data, 2, -1);
}
```

As expected, this fails to compile because `` no implementation for `usize + i8` `` .
I understand this is because the behavior of subtracting below zero is undefined for unsigned numbers.
However, it is unclear to me how I can achieve the wanted behavior in Rust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There’s [`usize::saturating_add_signed`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#method.saturating_add_signed):

```rust
fn get_elements(array: &[char], i: usize, dx: isize) -> (char, char) {
    let center = array[i];
    let other = array[i.saturating_add_signed(dx).min(array.len() - 1)];
    (center, other)
}
```

Note that I changed `dx` to `isize` for convenience (`isize::from(dx)` = `dx.into()` will work if you want to keep it `i8`) and `array` to `&[char]` because you don’t need the `Vec`ness.

Alternatively, you might find options like the following where the index passes through `isize` more readable. The only behavior difference is for `usize`s that don’t fit in `isize`, which it wouldn’t be unreasonable to consider out of scope in most cases.

```rust
let len: isize = array.len().try_into().unwrap();
let center = array[i];
let other = array[(i as isize + dx).clamp(0, len - 1) as usize];
(center, other)
```

> I understand this is because the behavior of subtracting below zero is undefined for unsigned numbers.

Subtracting below zero is actually well-defined to panic in debug builds and wrap in release, but it’s about being explicit, yes.